How to deal with asymptotics of $\log(1-x)$ when $x$ is approaching $1$?
Consider $$\log(1-x)$$ where $x=x(n)\rightarrow 1$ when $n\rightarrow \infty$.
What is the asymptotics of this function?
Related question

This looks a lot simpler than the recent related question whose answer you have accepted.

$\log(1-x)$ or $\log(1+x)$ ?

@ClaudeLeibovici minus. I am sorry

@ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much!

You are supposed to know the rules of this site. Please show some of your working first, please.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4307784/approximation-of-lnx-in-the-vicinity-of-x-0

It is not possible to describe the singular behaviour of the logarithm at the origin by simpler functions.

@Gary I see! I alternatively used the upper and lower bound of $\log x$ near $x=0$. https://rgmia.org/papers/v7n2/pade.pdf

It is true that $\lim _{x \to 0^ +  } x^\varepsilon  \log x \to 0$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Since you look at the behaviour of $\log(x)$ when $x \to 0^+$, have a look at this question where I proposed to use $$x\log(x)\sim \frac{5 (x-1) x \left(5 x^3+37 x^2+37 x+5\right)}{6 \left(x^4+16 x^3+36 x^2+16
   x+1\right)}$$
If you want a simpler approximation of mine
$$x\log(x)\sim  x^{\log (e-1)} \, (x-1)$$

$$
\log(1-x) = x+ \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} + \cdots .
$$
At $x=-1$ the alternating harmonic series converges to $\log 2$. The error is bounded by the absolute value of the first omitted term in the partial sum.
The analysis harder at $x= 1$ where you want to know how fast the logarithm approaches $-\infty$. Sorry I'm no help there.

but Taylor expansion works for $x\in(-1,1)$ and at boundary $\pm 1$ it might be inaccurate? I am not sure

@chloe I didn't read the question carefully enough. See my edit. I can delete my answer if it's no help.
